# Free up the memory used ImageView on Android 5

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I have problem with free up the memory from ImageView.
I test my application on Android 7 and I free memory by set `imageView.setImageBitmap(null)` and use `System.gc()` after that, but on Android 5 I see memory leak and I don't know what I can do, I try use `bitmap.recycle()` but it too doesn't  work.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    System.runFinalization();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    System.gc();
```

Comment: Hey Rasoul, your answer would become much better if you give it some context and explain what you have done and why, instead of just posting a code snippet. That way, future readers can find this answer more helpful and learn something from it.

Comment: I tryed it, but it does not help.
I use ImageLoader library for download image and after several downloads i do dump java heap and see some byte[] with different size

Comment: @just_kolala use picasso and glid